# find rows with peaks and bottoms from a pandas data frame on a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this,

```
col1     col2
 A        10
 B        12 
 C        16
 D        20
 E        18
 F        15
 G        23
 H        20
 I        19
 J        17
 K        21
 L        26
```

Now I want to find the peak and buttom from col2 and want to keep only those rows if it falls under peak or bottom.
for example, the the data frame I am looking for is,

```
col1     col2
 A        10
 D        20
 F        15
 G        23
 J        17
 L        26
```

I could do this using a for loop and store the indices by comparing the next and previous value. But it will take the longer time to execute. I am looking for some pythonic way/ pandas shortcuts to do it efficiently.

Comment: What do you mean by peak and bottom? What do you mean by "fall under peak or bottom"

Comment: I mean either a peak and bottom. (local maxima and minima) look at the output, you will get the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First idea is compare previous and next value returned from [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and for return also first and last values is testing with missing values:

```
s1 = df.col2.shift()
s2 = df.col2.shift(-1)

m1 = (s1 > df.col2) & (s2 > df.col2)
m2 = (s1 < df.col2) & (s2 < df.col2)

df = df[m1 | m2 | s1.isna() | s2.isna()]
```

Or better testing first and last values:

```
df = df[m1 | m2 | df.index.isin([0, len(df)-1])]

print (df)
   col1  col2
0     A    10
3     D    20
5     F    15
6     G    23
9     J    17
11    L    26
```

Or use [`argrelextrema`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.argrelextrema.html) for positions, join together by [`numpy.union1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.union1d.html) and select by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema

a = argrelextrema(df.col2.values, np.less_equal, order=1)[0]
b = argrelextrema(df.col2.values, np.greater_equal, order=1)[0]

df = df.iloc[np.union1d(a, b)]
print (df)
   col1  col2
0     A    10
3     D    20
5     F    15
6     G    23
9     J    17
11    L    26
```